# Ubercart add to cart form with quantity option per attribute

Tags: php, drupal, ubercart

I need the add to cart form on each product to display separate quantity fields so items of different attributes can be added at the same time. This is for a photography site, so it makes sense for the customer to order 2 6x4 prints and one 10x8.

Right now the add to cart form is something like this:

[image]

Here is a mockup of what I want to have:

[image]

I have no idea which hooks to use, or if it's even possible to add multiple product variants in one POST. Is anyone familiar enough with the Ubercart api to tell me how I can go about doing this.

Answer (score 1):

I found this googling for a solution to the same problem. Unfortunately I couldn't find anything.

So I made a patch and sent it in to an issue with a similar request - http://drupal.org/node/782154#comment-3925090

The patch isn't tested very well yet, but I will be going live with it or a subsequent solution in a couple of weeks.

Hope it helps.